# LibGDX: Render 2D dynamic fbo texture in 3d space

Tags: opengl, 3d, libgdx, 2d, framebuffer

this is my first attempt at a 3d game. My basic idea is that I want to have the player inside a cube, with each wall (all 6 faces) is rendered as 2d using a FrameBuffer and then draw into 3d space. I am currently using decals but I get weird bugs and I'm starting to think maybe there is a better approach. Is there?

Here is what it looks like so far:
[image]

Each wall is a 2d texture created using an fbo. For now there is only a color being drawn to each wall but eventually there will be 2d sprites and stuff.

Sometimes the blue wall completely renders and other time (like in the photo) there are black boxes that show up. Also, the red wall to the right is good, but there are also black boxes giving it a weird illusion.

So basically, I just need a fast way to render dynamic (60fps minimum) 2d textures in a 3d environment.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could be the near and far plane frustums of your camera clipping stuff. Make sure they are set to sensible values as compared to the scale of your decals.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I meant to close this thread. I decided to just use models. I was doing this for the LudumDare game jam so I was more pressed for time so I went for an easier solution. Thanks anyways :) I will close it after you see this message.